# How to create documentdb account using python in azure?

Tags: python, azure

Is any one know how to create document db account programatically for azure? I am aware about creating a database into present document db account.

Answer (score 0):

You can create DocumentDB accounts programmatically using Azure Resource Manager templates or the Azure Command-Line Interface (CLI). See [DocumentDB Automation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-automation-resource-manager-cli/) for details

Answer (score 0):

@Amol Shinde, Trying to use Azure SDK for Python to create documentdb account.

As reference, here is my sample code.

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient

subscription_id = 'xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx'
client_id = 'xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx'
client_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx'
tenant_id = 'xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx'

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id = client_id, secret = client_secret, tenant = tenant_id)

client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)

documentdb_params = {
    'location': 'westus',
    'properties':  {
        'name': 'myDocumentDb',
        'databaseAccountOfferType': 'Standard'
    }
}

client.resources.create_or_update('<your-resource-group>',
                                  'Microsoft.DocumentDB',
                                  '',
                                  'databaseAccounts',
                                  'myDocumentDb',
                                  '2015-06-01',
                                  documentdb_params)
```

And you can refer to the Azure SDK [document](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resourcemanagement.html).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the update.

for above code I got this error:
{"error":{"code":"InvalidRequestContent","message":"The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Error converting value \"{\"location\": \"westus\", \"properties\": {\"name\": \"myDocumentDb\", \"databaseAccountOfferType\": \"Standard\"}}\" to type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ResourceStack.Frontdoor.Data.Definitions.ResourceDefinition'. Path ''}

Comment: It wasn't worked for me but I have used below rest API to create it, and the API worked fine for me. 

"/subscriptions/<sub_id>/resourceGroups/<res_group_name>/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/<res_name>"

In header we just need to put Azure ARM authentication token.